# Javascript: Image to base64 for localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, base64, local-storage

Currently I have this code to set the `background-image` of a link:

```
$("a.link").css("background-image", "url('images/icon.png')";
```

And I want to improve it to store the image in `localStorage`:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("icon") {

  iconBase64 = //How to convert my image in images/icon.png to a base64 string?

  localStorage.setItem("icon", iconBase64);
}

$("a.link").css("background-image", "url(data:image/png;base64," + localStorage.getItem("icon") + ")");
```

Incredibly, I couldn't find any suitable solution for me... I've seen something about creating a `<canvas>` or something like that, but I guess there should be something easier... isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. There are ways to convert a binary blob (such as a PNG selected by the user via an `<input type="file" />` but not directly from an `<img>` tag.

However, using the canvas technique is fairly easy:

```
function getDataURL(img) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    return canvas.toDataURL();

}

var dataURL = getDataURL(document.querySelector('#myimg'));
```

Note this will only work if the both the `<img>` and calling script are located on the same domain (the reason I can't demo this on JSFiddle).

Answer (score 1):

Use canvas or XMLHTTPRequest+FileReader to get dataURL.

```
function getImageDataURL(imgURL, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function (){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        callback(canvas.toDataURL());
    };
    img.src = imgURL;
}
function getFileDataURL(fileURL, callback) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = function (e){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            callback(e.target.result); //DataURL
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.response);
    };
    oReq.open('get', fileURL, true);
    oReq.responseType='blob';
    oReq.send();
}
function setBG(dataURL){
    $("a.link").css("background-image", "url(data:image/png;base64," + dataURL + ")");
}
function test(){
    var dataURL = localStorage.getItem("icon");
    if (!dataURL) {
        //use getImageDataURL or getFileDataURL
        getImageDataURL('images/icon.png', function (dataURL){
            localStorage.setItem("icon", dataURL);
            setBG(dataURL);
        });
    } else {
        setBG(dataURL);
    }
}
test();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using a reader, but for an uploaded file that I created a preview of.

```
var file = "icon.png";
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    iconBase64 = e.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

However I have never tried this with a file from the server. Also, this should add the data:image/png;base64 already.